# What's the JavaScript equivalent of Ruby's "inspect"?

Tags: javascript, ruby, debugging

In Ruby, you can do `foo.inspect` and it outputs something sane for any object pretty much regardless of type.

How do I achieve the same thing in JavaScript?

Comment: What's wrong with `console.log(foo)`?

Comment: Matt's is the correct answer, IMHO.

Comment: @MattBall, @AaronGray..`console.log` is wrong, because, both `console.log("1")` and `console.log(1)`, will print the same output. It will not be possible to identify whether a variable's type using console.log.

Comment: @rubyprince sure it's possible. `console.log(typeof "1", "1")` – and you can write a wrapper around `console.log()` that does that for you.

Comment: @MattBall..in Ruby, if you print `"2".inspect` it prints `"2"` and if you print `2.inspect`, it prints `2` likewise, and if you give an object `a=Foo.new;a.item = 4;a.inspect` will print something of the sort `Object(Foo @item 4)` something of that sort. Something similar to what firebug or chrome inspector gives when we just enter a variable. we get an idea about what the variable is, what its structure is etc. I think he is asking, something which gives something similar to the firebug output from the code. Sure, `console.log` gives, a pretty good idea about the variable.

Comment: and sure we can add a breakpoint, from the code or from the inspector, and inspect the hell out of the variable :). But, I think he wants to know whether there is something similar to Ruby `inspect` in Javascript.

Comment: I personally think, Prototype `Object.inspect("1")`, is the similar one to Ruby inspect. I think `console.log` is the equivalent of `puts` in Ruby.

Comment: By default `console.log` does not permit assigning the output to a variable. In contrast Ruby `inspect` does. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462122/assign-console-log-value-to-a-variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possibly not the entirely general answer you're hoping for, since this introduces third-party dependencies into you application. However, they're worth mentioning:

- For applications using Prototype ([link](http://www.prototypejs.org/)) you can use `Object.inspect` ([link](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Object/inspect/))
- For applications using jQuery ([link](http://jquery.com/)) there's the `jquery-inspect` ([link](http://github.com/ssoper/jquery-inspect)) plugin

Answer (score 18):

`JSON.stringify(foo)` works pretty well.

Comment: This is the correct answer, inspect in ruby is a function/method that is readily available in the language. This answer comes closest to that.

Comment: Apart from looking ugly, this generally works. Hope they improve it in future versions of ECMAScript.

Comment: I came here looking for an alternative to this since it doesn't handle `undefined` and `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/reflection.html

Did that help?

Comment: This answer is link only, with no additional information.