# Assign console.log value to a variable

Tags: javascript, ruby, console.log, language-comparisons

How can I assign a JavaScript object to a variable which was printed using `console.log`?

I am in Chrome console. With Ruby I would use `test = _` to access the most recent item printed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could override standard `console.log()` function with your own, adding the behaviour you need:

```
console.oldLog = console.log;

console.log = function(value)
{
    console.oldLog(value);
    window.$log = value;
};

// Usage

console.log('hello');

$log // Has 'hello' in it
```

This way, you don't have to change your existing logging code. You could also extend it adding an array and storing the whole history of printed objects/values.

Comment: An elegant solution, but it would be nice to capture warnings and errors also. How would i accomplish that?

Comment: ReferenceError: $log is not defined

Answer (score 45):

If you want to do this to an object that has been already logged (one time thing), chrome console offers a good solution.

Hover over the printed object in the console, right click, then click on "Store as Global Variable". Chrome will assign it to a temporary var name for you which you can use in the console.

[image]

Comment: This needs more upvotes! Half the answers don't even address the actual question, and this is exactly it. Let's face it: overriding `console.log` is a pain, and I did not remember to do that *before* wanting to look at this thing that got logged.

Comment: What would be the temp var name?

Comment: @coco97 the var name is `temp` with an auto-increment number (i.e. `temp1`, `temp2`, `temp3`, ...).

Answer (score 18):

In Chrome developer tools, you may access last item by `$_`:

```
> 1+1;
  2
> $_
  2
```

Comment: Thanks @stewie but this doesn't work for objects printed by console.log (+1 because I didn't know about this feature)

Answer (score 5):

Derivative of mirrormx's answer, but more convenient. I don't need to write a function and can just put it in anywhere on the spur of the moment.

```
console.log(window.$log = data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is [chrome reference](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api) for comand line api. 
There is $_ variable but it "Returns the value of the most recently evaluated expression" not printed, you can make your own log function like this:

```
function log(data){
   console.log(data);
   return data;
}
// after that you can access last printed value by $_
```

Please, note that my function is for example, console.log possibilities is much more advanced