# How to access alert box or console output with selenium in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

My aim is to access js variable for a particular webpage and I want to print it in terminal/cmd for further process such as writing the Output into a file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
with open("list_links.txt","rb") as fs:
    data = fs.readlines()
    for line in data:
        print "checking for: ",line 
        baseurl = line
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.set_window_size(140, 800)
        driver.get(baseurl)
        driver.execute_script("alert(someVariable)")
```

where `txt` file consists for different links and I am opening every page and popping an alert box which is giving me the output in the browser.

Everything is Working Fine, **I just want to read/access the output which I am getting in the alert box**.

SO, Is there any way to do this?

Also if there any way to read the same from console.log output text, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following way to get an alert text

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert_text = alert.text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get value of `someVariable` without reading text content of alerts as follow:

```
var_text = driver.execute_script("""
                                 var someVariable = "someValue";
                                 return someVariable;
                                 """)

print(var_text) # Output- "someValue"
```

Comment: Thanks Guys, also is there any method to access console output ?

Comment: You can try to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462122/assign-console-log-value-to-a-variable, but I didn't try it personally, so I don't know whether it could be applicable in your case